# while clicking on button i can download file but what i want need to open file system whre the file going to download in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, electron

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function SaveToFile() {
  const [content, setContent] = useState('');

  const handleContentChange = (event) => {
    setContent(event.target.value);
  }

  const handleSave = () => {
    const file = new Blob([content], { type: 'text/plain' });
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'myFile.txt';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.body.removeChild(a);
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }, 0);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea value={content} onChange={handleContentChange} />
      <button onClick={handleSave}>Save to file</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

above code im using to download file so

i have no idea .....but

i can download file but what i want while clicking on button i need to open file system where the file going to save in react js

`your text`

Comment: interesting question. natively, JavaScript doesn't have a file handling support unlike most languages, because of security risks and restrictions from netscape, but am not sure about now, though.

Comment: I think what you are asking is 'saveAs' functionality. check this out https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/filesaver/api/saveAs/

Answer (score 0):

Window.showSaveFilePicker can help you.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showSaveFilePicker

This method has bad capability with browser but works with modern Chrome, Edge and Opera